# Find if integer is in one of multiple integer ranges (and pos in range), where range lengths are same and gap between lower bounds of ranges are same?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I actually need this solution for a programming problem, but as I need an equation, I'm posting it here on the Mathematics exchange.

I am looking for a fast way (ie. without iterating over each range and comparing against lower and upper bounds of range) to see if an integer is within one of multiple integer ranges, and also the position within the range. The ranges are all of the same length, and the gap between each range is the same. For example, one-time the ranges might be:

```
[0..1]
[10..11]
[20..21]
```

For this range, the range length (say, L) is always 2, and the gap (say, G) between the lower (and upper) bounds of each range is always 10.

Another time the ranges might be:

```
[2..4]
[9..11]
[16..18]
[23..25]
```

For this range, the range length (L) is always 3, and the gap (G) between the lower (and upper) bounds of each range is always 7.

Given the first range (from which L can be deduced), and the gap between ranges, G, how can I tell for any integer, N, if:

```
(a) the integer is within one of the ranges ?
(b) the position within the range ?
(c) an integer which shows which range (eg. 2 means second range)
```

The brute force approach would be to just iterate over each range and compare against each range, which may be the only option when the ranges are of differing lengths or the gaps between each range are different. However, I'm sure there must be a mathematical way to determine the information, (a) and (b), with an equation. Only problem is my brain is not providing me with the answer.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first range starts at $A$, and there are a total of $R$ ranges, then you can start by computing the quotient, $\alpha$, and remainder, $\beta$, when $N-A$ is divided by $G$, taking the remainder always to be nonnegative and between $0$ and $G-1$:
$$
\alpha:=\lfloor (N-A)/G\rfloor, \ \ \ \ \beta:=(N-A) \mod G, \ \ \ \ N-A=\alpha G+\beta.
$$
Then, if $\alpha<0$ or $\alpha\ge R$, $N$ is too small or too large to fall in any of the ranges.  If $0\le\alpha<R$ and $L\le\beta<G$, $N$ falls into the gap between two ranges or comes just after the last range.  In the remaining case, where $0\le \alpha<R$ and $0\le\beta<L$, $N$ falls within the range $\alpha+1$ and is in a position $\beta$ after the first element of this range (that is, it is the first element of the range if $\beta=0$, the second if $\beta=1$, and so on.)

Comment: Many thanks David! Your answer works perfectly and has made my code much more efficient!. Even more impressive is that you answered after just 13 minutes.

Comment: I will up-vote it once I have 15 rep points.